# Search differences into 3 multidimensional arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm kinda new in PHP, currently working in multidimensional arrays. I want to know how to compare 3 multidimensional arrays and put the results in a new one.

$array1 must prevail, that means, $array1 will compare changes of rate value in $array2 and after that, with the changes made in previous comparison, the new $array1 will be compared with $array3, the result will be a fourth array with the new changes.

Special condition, if the rate value is equal to 0 (zero), **IGNORE**.

Input.

```
$array1 = array (3) (

[0] => Array
        (
            [iso] => ZMW
            [rate] => 0.0000000
        )

[1] => Array
        (
            [iso] => MXP
            [rate] => 0.3200030
        )   

[2] => Array
        (
            [iso] => USA
            [rate] => 0.3234511
        )

[3] => Array
        (
            [iso] => YNC
            [rate] => 1.0000000
        )
);

$array2 = array (3) (

[0] => Array
        (
            [iso] => ZMW
            [rate] => 0.0000001
        )

[1] => Array
        (
            [iso] => MXP
            [rate] => 0.3200031
        )   

[2] => Array
        (
            [iso] => USA
            [rate] => 0.0000000
        )

[3] => Array
        (
            [iso] => YNC
            [rate] => 1.0000000
        )
);

$array3 = array (3) (

[0] => Array
        (
            [iso] => ZMW
            [rate] => 0.0000000
        )

[1] => Array
        (
            [iso] => MXP
            [rate] => 0.3200029
        )   

[2] => Array
        (
            [iso] => USA
            [rate] => 0.3234510
        )

[3] => Array
        (
            [iso] => YNC
            [rate] => 2.0000000
        )
);
```

Output:

```
$arrayresult = array (3) (

[0] => Array
        (
            [iso] => ZMW
            [rate] => 0.0000001
        )

[1] => Array
        (
            [iso] => MXP
            [rate] => 0.3200029
        )   

[2] => Array
        (
            [iso] => USA
            [rate] => 0.3234510
        )

[3] => Array
        (
            [iso] => YNC
            [rate] => 2.0000000
        )
);
```

Comment: Do the first dimension keys always line up? For example if key `0` is `ZMW` in $array1, can it be assumed that key `0` is also `ZMW` in array2 and array3? Also, are there any duplicate values? Does the iso value `ZMW` (or any other value) exist in any one array more than once?

Comment: [`array_column`](http://php.net/array_column), [`array_filter`](http://php.net/array_filter), [`array_merge`](http://php.net/array_merge).

Comment: @JonathanKuhn Good question. No, In some cases iso code will exists but in a different dimension key `ZMW` could be key `2`. No, there are no more than 2 same iso codes in one array, iso value is unique for each array. Thanks